# Question about the $\limsup$ of a bounded function on [0,1)

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $f:[0,1)\to\mathbb{R}_+$ be continuous and such that $f(x)\le C$ for all $x\in[0,1)$. My question is whether or not this is true:
$$
\limsup_{x\to 1^-} f(x) \le C
$$
Then, do we actually need the continuity of $f$?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's true.

No, continuity is not needed.